# How can I make my iFrame app work properly?

Tags: iframe, facebook-iframe

Ever since the apps directory got taken down, finding a way to embed my site in a Facebook page has been problematic. The best I could come up with is this: http://www.facebook.com/wcockcroftwebdesign?sk=app_102378836536403

which doesn't work properly. Please bear in mind that I've set it to show the app as a default. When you go to the app itself you get the wall of the app, which is now a page on its own -- not what I intended. I want http://apps.facebook.com/102378836536403/ to show up on my fan page as a default. What have I done wrong?

No doubt someone will tell me to look at the various bits of documentation, but the instructions given don't make sense to a noob, so if you can explain it in a way I understand, I would be very much obliged. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a facebook.com URL loading as the canvas URL of your page; this should be the URL where your app is running. Set this up by going to [developers.facebook.com/apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and selecting your app on the left side, if it's not already selected. Click "Edit settings" and look down at the bottom, you should see something like this:

[image: Canvas URL configuration]

Enter the URL of your site there and you should be golden.

If not, I've probably misunderstood what you're trying to do... :)

**EDIT**: it occurred to me right after posting that I probably did misunderstand what you're doing: you're trying to show your site *as a tab* on a facebook page. You're going to want the settings just below the previous image:

[image: Page tab configuration]